# Creating json object in mvc and returning from controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I need to create the following in a loop, my has "name" and "id" where name will be used for the value property of the json object and id will be used for the "data"  and query will be some string I can set.
I tried using keypair but could not figure out how to do this property.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
{

    "query": "Unit",
    "suggestions": [
        { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
        { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
        { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to return results for this autocomplete widget
https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: Please don't pout answers into questions. I've removed and will add as a wiki answer. If you want to answer your own question let me know and I'll delete the wiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to go full blown on this, but maybe create your own classes?

```
public class DataValuePair
{
    public string Data {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}

public class SearchResult
{
    public string Query {get;set;}
    public List<DataValuePair> Suggestions {get;set;}
}
```

And now you can return a JSON Result

```
return Json(mySearchResult);
```

Comment: you beat me to it, but figure it out so i will mark urs as an answer since its close to what I had to do

Answer (score 6):

You can just create an anonymous object. To return the JSON as indicated in your question, it would be

```
public JsonResult GetCities(string query)
{
  var data = new
  {
    query = "Unit",
    suggestions = new[]
    {
      new { value = "United Arab Emirates", data = "AE" },
      new { value = "United Kingdom", data = "UK" },
      new { value = "United States", data = "US" }
    }
  };
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Side note: Unsure of the purpose of the method parameter?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer from OP:**

Figured it out, below is the code

```
public ActionResult GetCities(string query)
    {
        var obj = new CitySuggestion();
        obj.suggestions.Add(new Suggestion { value = "test1", data = "test1" });
        obj.suggestions.Add(new Suggestion { value = "test2", data = "test2" });
        obj.suggestions.Add(new Suggestion { value = "test3", data = "test3" });

       return  Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), "application/json");
    }
    public class CitySuggestion
    {
        public CitySuggestion()
        {
            suggestions = new List<Suggestion>();
        }
        public List<Suggestion> suggestions
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
    public class Suggestion
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
    }
```